# How to extract segmentation as images after applying K Means using OpenCV C++?

Tags: c++, opencv, k-means, emgucv

I am new to OpenCV.

My image consists of Red, Green and Blue color pixels spread throughout at random. I have applied K Means and want to save clustering as different images. Suppose if I consider the number of clusters as 3, I want three images saved with the segmentation done by K Means.

The language I am using is C++. And will also be helpful if any suggestions for EMGUCV.

Thankful for responses!
Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: Please attach the code that you have used already to solve this problem. Attach the input and current outputs as well if possible,

Comment: @ZdaR Thank you for your editing and also for the quick response. I am using the general syntax for K Means viz. "kmeans(SampleImages, ClusterCount, Labels, TermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER | CV_TERMCRIT_EPS, 10, 1.0), Attempts, KMEANS_RANDOM_CENTERS, Centers);"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`bestLabels` argument to `kmeans`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d5/d38/group__core__cluster.html#ga9a34dc06c6ec9460e90860f15bcd2f88) (you call it 'Labels') lets you specify a cv::Mat where the method will store label indices for all input pixels. It has the same geometry as the input image.

Splitting the output to masks is rather simple. The masks can then be saved as files. Example code (not tested):

```
for (auto k = 0; k < K; ++k) {
    cv::Mat1b mask = (bestLabels == k);
    cv::imwrite("cluster_" + std::to_string(k) + ".png", mask);
}
```

Note you probably have to do a bit more for compositing the filename.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Yes, i tried with iterating the cluster index holding the pixel values in Labels with manually supplying the number of cluster. But the idea of for loop you suggested just attracted my attention. And for sure i will design the code for getting the input for number of clusters. Thankful again!